# Blogger Emporio theme: permanently show Drop-Shadow on homepage snippets

Tags: html, css, templates, blogger, dropshadow

My blog is https://www.firozemistry.com based on the Blogger Emporio theme (with custom domain).

When viewed on Desktop/Laptop, on the homepage when the cursor is hovered over a snippet, the snippet highlights with a drop-shadow.

How can I make this drop-shadow permanently visible on all snippets, even when the cursor is not hovering over a snippet. If possible I would like the drop-shadow to be visible on Mobile view also.

However the snippet image dims slightly when the drop-shadow is visible. I would like the snippet to not dim while at the same time having the drop-shadows visible.

I would be most grateful if an expert would kindly guide me on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS `.feed-view .post-wrapper`

```
.feed-view .post-wrapper{
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12),0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

Comment: @user:4095056 Hello Lalji, could you help me with this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448469/how-to-show-hamburger-menu-in-blogger-emporio-theme